# CSS grid/CSS flexbox doesn't render when I put it on my hosting server

Tags: html, css, debugging, flexbox, web-hosting

I'm trying to get my very first website up and live, please forgive me for being very new. I've managed to upload it to my web host through the FTP server. The problem lies in visiting the site. When you visit my website http://emcaldwell-dev.com/index.html any flexbox or CSS grid I've used doesn't show. When I open the HTML page on my local PC site it's working the way I want. My index page is supposed to be a flex container with two children using flexbox. On the portfolio page, it displays images one after another when I'm using the CSS grid to display a `3 1` fr box. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is what I see in your live URL: https://nimb.ws/0JpLn2 It's in a grid.

Comment: hmmm I've clear my cache even but still not seeing that on my screen. I mean would it just possibly be a browser issue? I will post a pic of what it looks like.

Comment: Yes, it is your browser issue. Unfortunately, this question would be closed because the error cannot be reproduced live.

Comment: Understandable. At least I know where to start. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from what I can see, your website is in a grid. If you can't see it correctly on your computer, try clearing your cache in your preferred browser to see if that solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that, however I'm relived at least I have somewhere to start. Going to look deeper into it.